# Replace multiple spaces with a single | (pipe)

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want a simple code to replace multiple spaces with a single | in a file.
Code must include input and output file path.

For example Input,

```
200  514099******2039      00  17/01/25                        0       592335                   557.00   586
```

Required Output,

```
200|514099******2039|00|17/01/25|0|592335|557.00|586
```

Kindly assist in this regard. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: We need to move this to `plzWritzThizCodezForzMePLzzzzzz.com`, do not put this on `stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-replace` function to replace one or multiple whitespaces (`\s`) with a pipe:

```
'200 514099******2039 00 17/01/25 0 592335 557.00 586' -replace '\s+', '|'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the emphasis is on **multiple** spaces

```
(Get-Content .\infile.txt ) -replace '\s{2,}','|' | Set-Content .\outfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you @LotPings. It worked as desired. Appreciated your effort.